# How to resolve Blazor Web Assembly slow loading issues

Tags: blazor-webassembly

I have an blazor Web Assembly project which contain more than 100 razor page. When I compile this project it takes long time to run and slow loading if I change something in razor page.
Please help to resolve this issues.

Note:-

When I run without any changes in razor pagem,then the performance of loading project is good.